# Cloudfront as a reverse proxy for backend

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have tried to put in place a CloudFront distribution that would forward requests using a CloudFront function to our external API GW (not the AWS one). However this creates an issue with CORS. I can make the CORS request working, however what I am trying to replace is a backend for frontend pattern that we have in place currently using an Apache server and single origin cookie.

```
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var headers = request.headers;
    var apigwurl = 'https://gatewayendpoint/'
    
    if (request.uri.startsWith('/api')) {
       request.uri = request.uri.replace('/gw/', '');
       
       var response = {
            statusCode: 302,
            statusDescription: 'Found',
            headers: {
                "location": { "value": apigwurl+request.uri}
            }
        }
        return response;
        
    }
    return request;
}
```

In essence what I am trying to do is replace in the most effective way the following rewrite function

```
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ https://api.backend.com/$1 [P,L]
```

Once the first request is done, the single cookie is set and used for authentication purposes to make calls to the BFF layer (Backend for Frontend).

Answer (score 0):

NGINX would be a good fit for a reverse proxy for backend and can be used as an API gateway.

I would suggest to use a solution/technology combination which is widely used. That way, you will not make your life difficult with rare technology combination and find better technical support and resources online.